# How can i tell my modalDialog to be automatic closed when an input changes (eg. a tab changes)?

Tags: r, shiny, reactable

I have this Shiny App with a `navbarPage` and two `tabPanel`s. In the first tab i have an `actionLink` which initializes a `modalDialog` including a `reactable` with cells as buttons. When i click on a button from the table i want to change the input from my `navbarPage`, i.e. change the `tabPanel` from "tabone" to "tabtwo". Simultaneously i want the `modalDialog` to be closed when the `tabPanel` changed. How can i tell my `modalDialog` to be closed then?

```
library(Shiny)
library(reactable)

ui = fluidPage(
  
  navbarPage(title = "tabs", id = "nav",
             
  tabPanel(title = "tabone",
           actionLink(inputId = "action", "open modalbox")),
  
  tabPanel(title = "tabtwo")
  
))

server = function(input, output, session){
  
  shinyInput = function(FUN, len, id, labels, ...) {
    inputs = character(len)
    for (i in seq_len(len)) {
      inputs[i] = as.character(FUN(paste0(id, i), label = labels[i], ...))
    }
    inputs
  }
  
 observeEvent(input$action, {
   showModal(
     modalDialog(
       tagList(reactableOutput(outputId = "table"))
     ))})
  
  output$table = renderReactable({
    data = tibble(c = "click to change navbar input") %>%
      mutate(c = shinyInput(actionButton, n(), 'id', labels = c, onclick = "Shiny.setInputValue('change', this.innerText)")) %>%
      reactable(data = .,
              sortable = FALSE,
              columns = list(
                `c` = colDef(
                  html = TRUE)
              ))})
    
  observeEvent(input$change, {
  updateTabsetPanel(session = session, inputId = "nav", selected = "tabtwo")
  })  
  
   
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `removeModal()` in `observeEvent` of `change` button.

```
library(shiny)
library(reactable)

ui = fluidPage(
  
  navbarPage(title = "tabs", id = "nav",
             
             tabPanel(title = "tabone",
                      actionLink(inputId = "action", "open modalbox")),
             
             tabPanel(title = "tabtwo")
             
  ))

server = function(input, output, session){
  
  shinyInput = function(FUN, len, id, labels, ...) {
    inputs = character(len)
    for (i in seq_len(len)) {
      inputs[i] = as.character(FUN(paste0(id, i), label = labels[i], ...))
    }
    inputs
  }
  
  observeEvent(input$action, {
    showModal(
      modalDialog(
        tagList(reactableOutput(outputId = "table"))
      ))
    })
  
  output$table = renderReactable({
    data = tibble(c = "click to change navbar input") %>%
      mutate(c = shinyInput(actionButton, n(), 'id', labels = c, onclick = "Shiny.setInputValue('change', this.innerText)")) %>%
      reactable(data = .,
                sortable = FALSE,
                columns = list(
                  `c` = colDef(
                    html = TRUE)
                ))})
  
  observeEvent(input$change, {
    updateTabsetPanel(session = session, inputId = "nav", selected = "tabtwo")
    removeModal()
  })  
  
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]